# Get url of ALL lists on a SharePoint 2013 site using JSOM

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, url, client-object-model

I'm trying to retrieve the url for all lists on the current SharePoint site. I've managed to get the title for each list, I've also found resources explaining how to get the url of one specific list. But my question is how do i get the url of every list on the site. If you take a look at the part `url:oList.get_url()`. You'd think there was a method like this to retrive the url from the enumerator, but it does not work.

```
this.get_lists = function(onSuccess, onFailure, url){
        this.setContext(url);

        var oWebsite = this.context.get_web();
        this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
        this.context.load(this.collList);

        function onSucceed () {
            var listEnumerator = this.collList.getEnumerator();

            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()){
                var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
                var current_oList = {
                    title:oList.get_title(),
                    url:oList.get_url()
                }
                onSuccess(current_oList);
            }
        }

        function onFail(sender, args){
            onFailure(args.get_message());
        }

        this.context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, onSucceed), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, onFail)
        );

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly load the URL using the `load` method

```
this.context.load(this.collList, "Include(Title, DefaultViewUrl)");
```

so your onSucceed will be like

```
function onSucceed () {
        var listEnumerator = this.collList.getEnumerator();

        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()){
            var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
            var current_oList = {
                title:oList.get_title(),
                url:oList.get_defaultViewUrl()
            }
            onSuccess(current_oList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what method call do i do once the success callback fires?

Comment: @ThomasLindauer I have updated the answer

Comment: Using `load` is it possible to add a `Where` clause? I'm trying to return only document libraries instead of all the lists. I've seen this syntax but can't get it working in javascript `var Libraries = clientContext.LoadQuery(Web.Lists.Where(l => l.BaseTemplate == 101));`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you asked for JSOM, you could also use REST:

```
/_api/Web/Lists?$expand=RootFolder&$select=RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl
```

You can ask for other properties as well, such as `Name`. `Url` didn't seem to work on my SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new JavaScript library added by Patterns and Practices team. That library uses the REST API and easy way in obtaining the result in less lines of code.

We require a pnp.js file, which is available from [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core/blob/master/dist/pnp.js)
To run the below code in IE include [fetch.js](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js) and [promise.js](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/blob/master/dist/lib/es6-promise.js) to the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/siteassets/scripts/fetch.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/siteassets/scripts/promise.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/siteassets/scripts/pnp.min.js"></script>
```

The below code returns all lists title and default view url.

```
$pnp.sp.web.lists.select('Title', 'DefaultViewUrl').get().then(function(data) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].Title + " - " + data[i].DefaultViewUrl);
}   });
```